# ionic capacitor run android --device TARGET_ID Application not opening on my phone

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to run an ionic project on my android phone. The usb debugging is **ON**. There are no errors on the terminal.

This is the command I'm using `ionic capacitor run android --device TARGET_ID`

This is the log on the terminal.

```
Build at: 2022-01-17T08:34:48.302Z - Hash: 5c98884b09c72022 - Time: 10541ms
> capacitor.cmd run android --target 1f693801
[capacitor] √ Copying web assets from www to android\app\src\main\assets\public in 8.69s
[capacitor] √ Creating capacitor.config.json in android\app\src\main\assets in 1.65ms
[capacitor] (node:3840) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at D:\Practise\ionic\sgmsls\node_modules\tslib\package.json.
[capacitor] Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
[capacitor] (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[capacitor] √ copy android in 8.77s
[capacitor] √ Updating Android plugins in 19.41ms
[capacitor] [info] Found 4 Capacitor plugins for android:
[capacitor]        @capacitor/app@1.0.7
[capacitor]        @capacitor/haptics@1.1.3
[capacitor]        @capacitor/keyboard@1.2.0
[capacitor]        @capacitor/status-bar@1.0.6
[capacitor] √ update android in 223.01ms
[capacitor] √ Running Gradle build in 13.18s
[capacitor] √ Deploying app-debug.apk to 1f693801 in 5.39s
```

But no application is installed or opened on my phone.

---

I've tried this with another way. `ionic capacitor run` and select `android`. The choose my device.

Comment: Try wireless debugging. If your machine and your mobile device is on same network(wifi) try these steps:
1) run command `adb tcpip 5555` 2) `adb connect 192.168.1.123:5555` your device IP you can get from wifi options of your device. then run command `ionic cap run android -l --external`.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib ```[INFO] Development server running!

       Local: http://localhost:8100
       External: http://192.168.1.64:8100, http://192.168.56.1:8100

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process

> capacitor.cmd run android --no-sync --target 192.168.1.67:5555
[capacitor] √ Running Gradle build in 6.78s
[capacitor] √ Deploying app-debug.apk to 192.168.1.67:5555 in 4.96s

[INFO] App deployed to device!

       Development server will continue running until manually stopped.

       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process``` but no application is being installed or opened

Comment: did you make any build of same application before? and installed it in your device?

Comment: I've run a few apps before following the same steps and they worked. I just tried creating a new app and running it on the phone, but idk why the new app isn't working either. It works on the Virtual device on android studio though. I haven't made any changes to my device settings. Do you think its because of some cache thingy? When running the new app, the application name is different and I also changed the appID in the capacitor.config.ts

Comment: Yes, this might be the issue, Check you application list from settings and see if your have any other application withs same bundle ID. or just try to restart both devices. machine and mobile.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib Yeah I guess that was it. I cleared all the cache and its working now. thank you. You can write an answer to this question and I'll mark that as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometime other application with same bundle ID create problems,
Check your applications list from settings and see if your have any other application withs same bundle ID. or just try to restart both devices. machine and mobile.

Also Try wireless debugging:

If your machine and your mobile device is on same network(wifi) try these steps with command:

1. `adb tcpip 5555`
2. `adb connect <your-device-ip>:5555` device IP you can get from wifi options of your device.
3. `ionic cap run android -l --external`